# "Needs to be repaired" vs. "needs repairing"

Tags: meaning, differences, infinitives, gerunds

Is there any difference in meaning between the following two sentences?

> 1. My car needs to be repaired.
> 2. My car needs reparing.

Comment: I think there's a related question somewhere.

Comment: @Barrie look no further than OP's previous question.

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker I've always understood these to mean exactly the same thing, however 'needs repairing' feels more informal to me. I hear this construction far more than 'needs to be repaired'.